# List Item "value does not fall within the expected range" error--strange behavior

Tags: 2010, development

I am getting the error on the following line for a timer job:

```
if (listItem["Department"] != null)
```

Normally this error indicates that it cannot find the field, but there are no spaces and the field label name and strong name are the same. Furthermore, if I write it like this:

```
if (listItem.Fields["Department"] != null)
```

I no longer get the error.

The problem is I am trying to call `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` on the object and cannot call it by Fields. Is there some nuanced difference between the two that I'm missing that's causing this error?

EDIT: I figured out the problem. I had set 
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
and "Department" was a new field and was not set in the ViewFields, so as far as the timer job could tell the field didn't exist. I simply needed to add the field into the list of fields in ViewField.

Comment: If you've resolved this, please post your solution as an answer for future visitors.

Comment: I tried to do this before but was blocked from posting an answer. I can do it now it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had set query.ViewFieldsOnly = true; and "Department" was a new field and was not set in the ViewFields, so as far as the timer job could tell the field didn't exist. I simply needed to add the field into the list of fields in ViewField.

Comment: What do you mean by in ViewField?

Answer (score 0):

The first line checks if the value of the data in the column "Department" is null for that specific list item.

The second line checks if the `SPField` object "Department" is null.

If the `SPField` exists on the list, it should never be null, but the data stored in that field for a specific list item may be.

Comment: It's not that the line is resolving incorrectly, it's that there is an exception and gives the "value does not fall within the expected range" error. Please ignore the "if" statement, I am talking purely about the behavior of getting the value of the list item. The SPField line was just an example to show that the value can be pulled with the name "Department".

Comment: Does the field happen to have a different internal field name?

Answer (score 0):

This error System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range with exception message Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow)  is due to throttling limit set at List View Lookup Threshold settings in WebApplication.

To resolve this error, Open the SharePoint Central Administration site and click  “Manage Web Application” link located under Application Management Group. Select the web application that has the problem. Select the “Resource Throttling” link under the “General Settings”

Navigate to List View Lookup Threshold section and change the value to a higher value depending on the count of Lookup, Person/Group, or workflow status field available in the list that caused the issue.

Comment: I think that you are right as I get this error only when I execute for more than 500 items.(in batches of 100)